# How to get the parent keypath in json file?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, data-structures

In python can we get the parent key path for a key, My json looks like following.. 
For example if i input a1: it should give: PROJ1/LOB1. All keys inside list[] are unique

```
{
    'PROJ1': {
        u'LOB1': [u'a1', u'a2'],
        u'LOb2': [u'v1', u'v2'],
        u'LOBA': [u'o1', u'oa', u'o2', u'o3'],
        u'LOBX': [u'n1', u'n2'],
        u'LOB': [u'b1', u'b2']
    },
  'PROJ12': {
        u'LOBa': [u'aa1', u'aa2'],
        u'LOBX': [u'vx1', u'vx2']
    },
}
```

I found this on a different thread but its not working for the above data. failing with :  `unhashable type: 'list'`

```
def keypaths(myDict):
    for key, value in myDict.items():
        if isinstance(value, collections.Mapping):
            for subkey, subvalue in self.keypaths(value):
                yield [key] + subkey, subvalue
        else:
            yield [key], value

reverse_dict = {value: keypath for keypath, value in keypaths(example_dict)}
```

Comment: Your data ran fine against the code.  Where are you getting the error?

Comment: @Idlehands i forgot to add this line: `reverse_dict = {value: keypath for keypath, value in keypaths(example_dict)}`

Comment: Your values are `list` and `dict`s cannot accept this data type as keys.  It is possible to make a string representation of the `list` by using `str(value)` which the `dict` will then accept as keys, but I'm not sure if that's what you want to achieve.

Comment: I am trying to get the keypath for a key,  if i input a1: it should give: PROJ1/LOB1. All keys inside list[] are unique

Comment: _What_ should give: PROJ1/LOB1? What does creating the reverse dict have to do with inputting a `1` and getting the desire result (from _something_)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to drill down the `list`s of values returned to get each of the `a1`, `a2`... etc.  You can make a minor modification to the `keypaths` function to flip the keys/values being returned::

```
import collections

sample = {
    'PROJ1': {
        u'LOB1': [u'a1', u'a2'],
        u'LOb2': [u'v1', u'v2'],
        u'LOBA': [u'o1', u'oa', u'o2', u'o3'],
        u'LOBX': [u'n1', u'n2'],
        u'LOB': [u'b1', u'b2']
    },
    'PROJ12': {
        u'LOBa': [u'aa1', u'aa2'],
        u'LOBX': [u'vx1', u'vx2']
    },
}

def keypaths(myDict):
    for key, value in myDict.items():
        if isinstance(value, collections.Mapping):
            for subvalue, subkey in keypaths(value):
                yield subvalue, [key] + subkey
        elif isinstance(value,list):
            for i in value:
                yield i, [key]
        else:
            yield value, [key]

my_dict = {k:i for k, i in keypaths(sample)}
```

This assumes all your values are unique, otherwise the paths get overwritten.

Alternatively, you could have done the same without modifying `keypaths` function (if it's needed for other purposes):

```
def keypaths(myDict):    
        for key, value in myDict.items():
            if isinstance(value, collections.Mapping):
                for subkey, subvalue in keypaths(value):
                    yield [key] + subkey, subvalue
            else:
                yield [key], value

    my_dict = {i: keypath for keypath, value in keypaths(sample) for i in value}
```

Note this alternative only works assuming all your values are `list`s (otherwise the dictionary comprehension would fail).

**Output:**

```
{'a1': ['PROJ1', 'LOB1'],
 'a2': ['PROJ1', 'LOB1'],
 'aa1': ['PROJ12', 'LOBa'],
 'aa2': ['PROJ12', 'LOBa'],
 'b1': ['PROJ1', 'LOB'],
 'b2': ['PROJ1', 'LOB'],
 'n1': ['PROJ1', 'LOBX'],
 'n2': ['PROJ1', 'LOBX'],
 'o1': ['PROJ1', 'LOBA'],
 'o2': ['PROJ1', 'LOBA'],
 'o3': ['PROJ1', 'LOBA'],
 'oa': ['PROJ1', 'LOBA'],
 'v1': ['PROJ1', 'LOb2'],
 'v2': ['PROJ1', 'LOb2'],
 'vx1': ['PROJ12', 'LOBX'],
 'vx2': ['PROJ12', 'LOBX']}
```

Note this only works assuming all your values are `list`s (otherwise the dictionary comprehension would fail), and with unique values (otherwise the keypaths get overwritten for duplicate values).

Now all you have to do to get the `keypath` is:

```
my_dict.get('a1')
# ['PROJ1', 'LOB1']

my_dict.get('o1')
# ['PROJ1', 'LOBA']

my_dict.get('not exist')
# None
```